# egrep matching lines that shouldn't match

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I am trying to find out if any of the floats in the first column containing floats in a CSV have a 1 after the decimal point. Here is an example row from my CSV:

> 1082805252197942751,34225793738713276,serialtooldata,1,Goals,75512140,125.0,63.0,29.0,1,,,,0,899,,

The seventh column is the one I am interested in, and in the row above it does not have a 1 after the decimal point (*125.0*)

I've come up with two potential regular expressions:

```
^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[a-z0-9]+,[0-9]+,[A-Za-z0-9\ ]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.1
```

or

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\ ,]+\.1
```

These both seem to work, i.e. on a regex test page (like regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/Cc0Q1U/1) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/QcIyqB/1)) the line correctly fails to match either regex. But when I try them at the terminal like this

```bash
egrep ^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[a-z0-9]+,[0-9]+,[A-Za-z0-9\ ]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.1 tool_data_160321.csv
```

or

```bash
egrep ^[A-Za-z0-9\ ,]+\.1 tool_data_160321.csv
```

then the line is listed as a match. Why does `egrep` think the line matches either regex when it doesn't?

Comment: FYI To make _extra_ sure that what you're trying to match is actually what you want to match, just use the `-o` flag.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are missing quotes. The backslash is interpreted by the shell, and the grep command gets just `.1`, not `\.1`, so it matches any character followed by `1`.

It's best to quote the whole string:

```
egrep '^[A-Za-z0-9\ ,]+\.1' tool_data_160321.csv
```

Or in this case quote the quote character:

```
egrep ^[A-Za-z0-9\ ,]+\\.1 tool_data_160321.csv
```

Note that the second example can still lead to surprises depending on files present, so just quote the whole string, that is never wrong.

Comment: Thanks! The other solution I just found was to include the dot as the only option, as it does not need escaping inside option brackets, i.e. `^[A-Za-z0-9\ ,]+[.]1`

Comment: Yes, you can rewrite the regex to not need a backslash. Note also that space doesn't require a backslash, whether in a character set or outside. But it is needed to prevent the shell from splitting the regex. Just use single quotes unless you are sure you don't need them.

Comment: And in default Zsh, or in Bash with `failglob` set, the second will error out, so better just quote everything that looks like a shell glob. Also, the ERE `[A-Za-z0-9\ ,]` will match a backslash too. In the first command here `egrep` does see it because it's quoted.